# @azure/msal-node -> User auth to access Azure Vault

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, electron, saml

So,

I've got a test azure instance and I'm trying to get access to a secret in a vault.

I've created the vault and now I want to access it with an electron application. I do not wish to have any client secrets anywhere on the application. So I am trying to get a bearer token to present to the vault using an authorized user and only the registered application's ID

[Image of Vault](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVWvt.png)

In this case the user in question is part of a group that in the vault's access policies has Get and List for secrets.

I have an application with a MSAL authentication added.

[Image of application registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oucKI.png)

I'm attempting to make use of some very slightly modified versions of this code base example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-desktop

global.api.azure

```js
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/
// Azure key Vault (API Key Storage / etc.) 

"use strict";
const {BrowserWindow} = require("electron")
const {
    PublicClientApplication,
    CryptoProvider
} = require("@azure/msal-node")
const api = require("../api/api")

// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const { protocol } = require("electron");

/**
 * CustomProtocolListener can be instantiated in order
 * to register and unregister a custom typed protocol on which
 * MSAL can listen for Auth Code reponses.
 *
 * For information on available protocol types, check the Electron
 * protcol docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol/
 */
class CustomProtocolListener {
  hostName;
  /**
   * Constructor
   * @param hostName - A string that represents the host name that should be listened on (i.e. 'msal' or '127.0.0.1')
   */
  constructor(hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName; //A string that represents the host name that should be listened on (i.e. 'msal' or '127.0.0.1')
  }

  get host() {
    return this.hostName;
  }

  /**
   * Registers a custom string protocol on which the library will
   * listen for Auth Code response.
   */
  start() {
    const codePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      protocol.registerStringProtocol(this.host, (req, callback) => {
        const requestUrl = new URL(req.url);
        const authCode = requestUrl.searchParams.get("code");
        if (authCode) {
          resolve(authCode);
        } else {
          protocol.unregisterProtocol(this.host);
          reject(new Error("No code found in URL"));
        }
      });
    });

    return codePromise;
  }

  /**
   * Unregisters a custom string protocol to stop listening for Auth Code response.
   */
  close() {
    protocol.unregisterProtocol(this.host);
  }
}

const REDIRECT_URI = "msald3e41458-b256-4b01-87c2-54c9a4db1eef://auth";

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "d3e41458-b256-4b01-87c2-54c9a4db1eef",
      authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/fullphaseroutlook.onmicrosoft.com`,
    },
  };

class azure { 
    constructor() {
        /**
         * Initialize a public client application. For more information, visit:
         * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/initialize-public-client-application.md
         */
        this.clientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
        this.account = null;
    
        // Initialize CryptoProvider instance
        this.cryptoProvider = new CryptoProvider();
    
        /**
         * To demonstrate best security practices, this Electron sample application makes use of
         * a custom file protocol instead of a regular web (https://) redirect URI in order to
         * handle the redirection step of the authorization flow, as suggested in the OAuth2.0 specification for Native Apps.
         */
        this.customFileProtocolName = REDIRECT_URI.split(":")[0];
    
        this.setRequestObjects();
      }
    
      // Creates a "popup" window for interactive authentication
      static createAuthWindow() {
        return new BrowserWindow({
          width: 400,
          height: 600,
        });
      }
    
      /**
       * Initialize request objects used by this AuthModule.
       */
      setRequestObjects() {
        const requestScopes = ["User.Read"];
    
        this.authCodeUrlParams = {
          scopes: requestScopes,
          redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
        };
    
        this.authCodeRequest = {
          scopes: requestScopes,
          redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
          code: null,
        };
    
        this.pkceCodes = {
          challengeMethod: "S256", // Use SHA256 Algorithm
          verifier: "", // Generate a code verifier for the Auth Code Request first
          challenge: "", // Generate a code challenge from the previously generated code verifier
        };
      }
    
      async login() {
        const authResult = await this.getTokenInteractive(this.authCodeUrlParams);
        return this.handleResponse(authResult);
      }
    
      async logout() {
        if (this.account) {
          await this.clientApplication.getTokenCache().removeAccount(this.account);
          this.account = null;
        }
      }
    
      async getToken(tokenRequest) {
        let authResponse;
        const account = this.account || (await this.getAccount());
        if (account) {
          tokenRequest.account = account;
          authResponse = await this.getTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
        } else {
          const authCodeRequest = {
            ...this.authCodeUrlParams,
            ...tokenRequest,
          };
    
          authResponse = await this.getTokenInteractive(authCodeRequest);
        }
    
        return authResponse.accessToken || null;
      }
    
      async getTokenSilent(tokenRequest) {
        try {
          var data = await this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
          console.log(data)
          return data 
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(
            "Silent token acquisition failed, acquiring token using pop up"
          );
          const authCodeRequest = {
            ...this.authCodeUrlParams,
            ...tokenRequest,
          };
          return await this.getTokenInteractive(authCodeRequest);
        }
      }
    
      async getTokenInteractive(tokenRequest) {
        /**
         * Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) Setup
         *
         * MSAL enables PKCE in the Authorization Code Grant Flow by including the codeChallenge and codeChallengeMethod parameters
         * in the request passed into getAuthCodeUrl() API, as well as the codeVerifier parameter in the
         * second leg (acquireTokenByCode() API).
         *
         * MSAL Node provides PKCE Generation tools through the CryptoProvider class, which exposes
         * the generatePkceCodes() asynchronous API. As illustrated in the example below, the verifier
         * and challenge values should be generated previous to the authorization flow initiation.
         *
         * For details on PKCE code generation logic, consult the
         * PKCE specification https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636#section-4
         */
    
        const { verifier, challenge } = await this.cryptoProvider.generatePkceCodes();
        this.pkceCodes.verifier = verifier;
        this.pkceCodes.challenge = challenge;
        const popupWindow = azure.createAuthWindow();
    
        // Add PKCE params to Auth Code URL request
        const authCodeUrlParams = {
          ...this.authCodeUrlParams,
          scopes: tokenRequest.scopes,
          codeChallenge: this.pkceCodes.challenge, // PKCE Code Challenge
          codeChallengeMethod: this.pkceCodes.challengeMethod, // PKCE Code Challenge Method
        };
    
        try {
          // Get Auth Code URL
          const authCodeUrl = await this.clientApplication.getAuthCodeUrl(
            authCodeUrlParams
          );
          const authCode = await this.listenForAuthCode(authCodeUrl, popupWindow);
          // Use Authorization Code and PKCE Code verifier to make token request
          const authResult = await this.clientApplication.acquireTokenByCode({
            ...this.authCodeRequest,
            code: authCode,
            codeVerifier: verifier,
          });
    
          popupWindow.close();
          return authResult;
        } catch (error) {
          popupWindow.close();
          throw error;
        }
      }
    
      async listenForAuthCode(navigateUrl, authWindow) {
        // Set up custom file protocol to listen for redirect response
        const authCodeListener = new CustomProtocolListener(
          this.customFileProtocolName
        );
        const codePromise = authCodeListener.start();
        authWindow.loadURL(navigateUrl);
        const code = await codePromise;
        authCodeListener.close();
        return code;
      }
    
      /**
       * Handles the response from a popup or redirect. If response is null, will check if we have any accounts and attempt to sign in.
       * @param response
       */
      async handleResponse(response) {
        if (response !== null) {
          this.account = response.account;
        } else {
          this.account = await this.getAccount();
        }
        return response;
      }
    
      /**
       * Calls getAllAccounts and determines the correct account to sign into, currently defaults to first account found in cache.
       * https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-common/docs/Accounts.md
       */
      async getAccount() {
        // need to call getAccount here?
        const cache = this.clientApplication.getTokenCache();
        const currentAccounts = await cache.getAllAccounts();
    
        if (currentAccounts === null) {
          console.log("No accounts detected");
          return null;
        }
    
        if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
          // Add choose account code here
          console.log(
            "Multiple accounts detected, need to add choose account code."
          );
          return currentAccounts[0];
        } else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
          return currentAccounts[0];
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
}

const vaultURL = "https://vault-test.vault.azure.net/"
class vault extends api{
    constructor(config){
        super(config)
        this.base = vaultURL
        this.headers = { 
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${config.token}`,
        }
    }
    async getSecret(secretName){
        return await this._req(`secrets/${secretName}/`,{
            method: "GET",
        })
    }
}

module.exports = { azure, vault }
```

```js
async function go(){
    var login = new global.api.azure.azure()
    var resp = await login.login() 
    var vault = new global.api.azure.vault({
        token: resp.accessToken
    })
    var secret = await vault.getSecret("test")
}
go()
```

The "extends API" is little more then a wrapper for the axios npm package. Everything for the most part works fine.
[Login Prompt in Electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPnVj.png)

The login prompt is presented, the user logs in and the correct account is retrieved along with a bearer token

[Bearer Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HESlN.png)

However the vault specifies that the Audience is invalid

[Vault Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGkoc.png)

I know I'm not presenting the correct audience in the scope, but I was curious how I would go about doing that. I tried adding the Azure Key Vault / User Impersonation API permission under the registered app; however, when changing

```
const requestScopes = ["User.Read"];
```

To something like user_impersonation, the CustomProtocolListener returns an error that the code was undefined / null. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For KV, you need to define the entire URL of the scope, you cannot pass only user_impersonation. The short version of the scopes can only be used with MS Graph. For example, the below are equivalent:

```
const requestScopes = ["User.Read"];
const requestScopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"];
```

Try changing your scopes array to the following, that should do the trick:

```
const requestScopes = ["https://vault.azure.net/user_impersonation"];
```

Comment: That appears to have done the trick. I also ended up having to add ?api-version=7.0 to the end of the request string. I was not aware graph permissions could be inherently shorthanded and hence why it was so in their own script. Thank you.